# creating stub files using a wadl file in j2me

Tags: web-services, java-me, midlet, midp, wadl

Hello
i want to create **stubs using a WADL web service**.

i **know** how to create **stubs from wsdl** file using stub generator, wscompile 
even from netbeans j2me web service client

but i have a **WADL** file and i am creating stubs same way as WSDL then getting following error

```
Stub Generation Failed:
error: modeler error: expected root element "definations"(in namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"),
found element "application"(in namespace "http://research.sun.com/wadl/2006/10")
```

what is wrong here?? am i missing something or there is some different way
of creating stubs of WADL file??

as error is showing expected WSDL i think there should some other way of creating stubs using WADL.

**Is it possible to create stubs of WADL**